# Scheduled Recurring email Google APPs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a code that will read the current time and determined which shift we are PM or AM, this date should also give me the day of the week because I will use the day of the week on the email title and body. However, I am still stuck on the logic to send the email without any of those requirements.

I am currently facing this issue where the code runs, but the email never gets sent. Can someone please help me?

Here is my code:

```
function sendemail() {
    var file = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1vQIpduKw8qp65oNMJt5XsTNOMQEsNaR8FA64kL1GXi0')
    const d = new Date()
    let day = d.getDay()

    var emailcontent = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CO Plan Release").getRange("B2:G22")
}

function sendEmail() {
    var recipients = 'jessica.sartori@gmail.com'
    var text = 'CO Plan Review'
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, text, testTableHTML(emailcontent))
}

function testTableHTML() {
    var file = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1vQIpduKw8qp65oNMJt5XsTNOMQEsNaR8FA64kL1GXi0')
    emailcontent = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CO Plan Release").getRange("B2:G22")
    return (tableHTML(emailcontent))
}

function tableHTML(emailcontent) {
    var data = emailcontent.getDisplayValues()
    var taille = emailcontent.getFontSizes()
    var fond = emailcontent.getBackgrounds()
    var couleur = emailcontent.getFontColors()
    var police = emailcontent.getFontFamilies()
}
```

I tried different ways of doing this mail function but none of them seem to work. Can someone help with
-Making the function email work
-Getting the correct logic to send the email based on the day they are access the code

Comment: tableHTML does not return anything

Comment: `emailcontent` you `getRange()` but never `getValues()`; and the purpose of `tableHTML` is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking several questions here - but they are not all solvable because of lack of information. Some things, such as the format and content of *your* specific email should, I suggest be carried over to a new question.

This answer shows

- how to identify AM/PM
- how to identify the day of the week
- how to source recipient subject and body content from the spreadsheet
- how to add the day of the week to the subject
- how to insert the Shift identifier into the body
- how to send an email

---

```
function sendDailyEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetName = "CO Plan Release"
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)

  // get the spreadsheet data
  var data = sheet.getRange("B2:B6").getValues()
  var recipient = data[0][0]
  var subjectPrefix = data[1][0]

  // some variables
  var dayNames = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  var shiftTime = "";

  // build the components
  // day
  var d = new Date()
  var day = d.getDay() // returns the day of the week// Sunday - Saturday : 0 - 6
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the day number is "+day) // 1 = Monday
  var month = dayNames[day]
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the day of the week is "+month); // "Monday"

  // AM or PM
  var shiftTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "a");
  // Logger.log(shiftTime)//DEBUG
  // assign the AM/PM options values
  if (shiftTime == "AM"){
    var shiftOption = data[2][0]
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: it is before 12 noon on Day#:"+day)
  }
  else{
    var shiftOption = data[3][0]
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: it is after 12 noon on Day#:"+day)
  }
  
  // create subject
  var subject = subjectPrefix+month
  // Logger.log(subject)// DEBUG

  // create body
  var body = data[4][0]
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Original body: "+body)
  body = body.replace("XYZ", shiftTime)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: revised body: "+body)


  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient,subject,body);
 
}
```

---

**SPREADSHEET - sample data**

[image: spreadsheet]

---

**EMAIL - as received**

[image]

Comment: You helped me figure out a big portion of the code I really appreciate. However the issue I am having is that I need to copy from the sheets the same format, colors, sizes etc. And it is not working at all! 

 Do you have any suggestion of what I can do to ??

Comment: Jessica, as I read your question, you were presenting two problems. 1) how to factor the day and shift into an email, and 2) how to actually send an email. Because we had no data nor an example of the expected result, we couldn't comment on the effect of `testTableHTML` in your email. as I said in the opening sentence to this answer `Some things, such as the format and content of your specific email should, I suggest be carried over to a new question.`